# Process ID exhaustion in Linux

Tags: linux, pid

What happens if Linux Operating System runs out of process ID ?  Will older processes be deleted to free up space to accommodate future requests ?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are asking what happens when the process limit has been reached.  In that case, the system doesn't allow new processes to be created until existing ones exit and get cleaned up.  This means nobody can log in, and the system is essentially unusable.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.